# List all combinations of combinations

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools, combinatorics

I am trying to list out all the possible combinations of groups of 3 that one can make of 6 people. `(A, B, C, D, E, F)`

- The order doesn't of the group doesn't matter
- The order of the pair doesn't matter

Possible combinations:

```
{(B,D),(C,E),(G,H)}

{(B,C),(D,E),(G,H)}

{(B,E),(C,D),(G,H)}
```

I could only get as far to write:

```
from itertools import combinations
x = combinations('ABCDEF', 2)
z = [y for y in x]
```

I have no idea on how I should create combinations out of combinations, the docs is not to much help. I think I have to someone create an algorithm from scratch.

- I know that there should be 15 total combinations to list

Comment: @Seraf I dont think so

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this as a backtracking problem. First, you need to find all the permutations. After that, you should slice the lists. For example: first permutation is [A,B,C,D,E,F]. You will slice it like this[(A,B),(C,D),(E,F)], second permutation will be [A,B,C,D,F,E] and  slice is [(A,B),(C,D),(F,E)]. And so on.