# Find every possible disposition of elements in a list keeping elements and list length

Tags: python, list, combinations

I would like to find every combination of elements in a list, by switching the order of the elements, while keeping their count and the length of the list.

For example, for the list:

```
[1,2,1,3]
```

I would like to obtain the following:

```
[1,1,2,3]    
[1,1,3,2]
[1,2,1,3]
[1,2,3,1]
[1,3,1,2]
[1,3,2,1]
[2,1,1,3]
[2,1,3,1]
[2,3,1,1]
[3,1,1,2]
[3,1,2,1]
[3,2,1,1]
```

Be aware that same elements, such as the two 1 in the original list, are not seen as separate ones, so the two possibilities `[1a,1b,2,3]` and `[1b,1a,2,3]` must be counted as one

Comment: isn't that exactly what `itertools.permutations` do ? but permutations return 24 elements, you have only 12 elements there.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think `set(itertools.permutations)` will do it.

Comment: @RuthC yes, figured it out

Comment: `permutations` AFAIK does not treat repeated elements in list as requested in the last sentence. One working solution would be `set(permutations([...]))`, but something more performant may exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want permutations with duplicates removed (since there are 2 identical elements), using a `set` and converting to `list` each element (or leave as tuples)

```
import itertools

s = [1,2,1,3]
for x in set(itertools.permutations(s)):
    print(list(x))
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 3]
```

this yields 12 elements, against 24 when using `permutations` but since there are 2 identical elements, the number is divided by 2.

as comprehension:

```
result = [list(x) in set(itertools.permutations(s))]
```

note that in general, using `set` to drop duplicates from `combinations` or `permutations` isn't the most performant solution. Here it's easy and not so lossy since the result/computation ratio isn't exponential (I had tried this technique here and that was too wasteful: [List all combinations of combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658604/list-all-combinations-of-combinations), computing 720 permutations to get a list of 15 groups).

Comment: it's already a duplicate (I should have known) and easy but yes one-liners aren't always the most efficient, when complexity matters